# Unable to collect charles proxy logs

Tags: logging, charles-proxy

Installed the charles proxy in my system and downloaded certificate but when I launch the charles proxy and try to collect the charles proxy logs browser is showing "connection is not private" and when I quit the charles proxy window things work fine again and browser starts to load again how to resolve this issue?

In documentation it's written to turn off firewall, antivirus & VPN but I don't have antivirus & VPN so I turned off firewall from control panel but still this issue is there, I was expecting that I could collect charles proxy logs gracefully with browser open

Comment: Have you cleared browser cache to remove potential pinned certificates? Which URLs have you tried and which browser and OS do you use?